# Increment user's input

Tags: python, loops, input, while-loop, increment

The program asks a user three questions:

1. Enter the number you want me to start counting in;
2. Enter the number you want me to end in; and
3. How much do you want to increment by?

From the questions, you can see what I want the program to do.

My problem is that I can manually increment the `start` number by putting it inside the `while` loop, but I cannot incorporate this as a user's input.

```
#Demonstrates user's input and increment.

start = int(input("Enter the number you want me to start counting in: "))
end = int(input("Enter the number you want me to end in:  "))
increment = int(input("How much do you want to increment by? "))

while start < end:
    start += 1
    print(start)


input("Press the enter key to exit..")
```

I know that the third question in the program is useless because it has no connection to the actual loop, but I've put it in there because that would be part of my final program.

Comment: Then why don't you *try using `increment` in the loop*?!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print the numbers from `start` to `end` including the extremes, the condition on your `while` is not correct, because when the number `start` that you are going to print is exactly equal to `stop`, the condition  `start<stop`  is `False` and so the body of the `while` is not executed.

A correct condition is either

```
while not start > end:
    ...
```

or

```
while start !> end:
    ...
```

or eventually

```
while start <= end:
    ...
```

All these three ways of writing the test evaluate to `True` when `start` equals `end`.

As a side note, in my opinion you better don't use `start` for the `while` loop, rather introduce an auxiliary variable, like in

```
incr = 1
current = start
while current <= end:
    print(current)
    current = current + incr
```

#### Post Scriptum

There are more idiomatic ways (more *pythonic* ways, someone will tell you) to get your job done, but for now let's keep simple things as simple as possible... Further, I hope that you have not missed the implicit hint on the use of an increment...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while start < end:
    start += increment
    print(start)
```

Comment: I realize that you're just replicating the OP program structure, but I suspect that they _really_ want to print the start value. And they probably want to print the end value, too, if (end - start) % increment == 0.

Answer (score -2):

Use the Python `range()` function. It takes three arguments:

1. starting point
2. ending point
3. increment each time

For example:

```
def increment(start, end, increment):
     for i in range(a, b, increment):
         print(i)
```

Comment: Why would you create a new function for this, rather than just inline the `range` call? Also, your parameters don't match the arguments to `range`, and using the same name for a function and one of its parameters is a bad move.